# Load multiple fragments with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

What is the most efficient way to load a resource using Ajax and then replace the contents of `#listing` and `#contextActions`?

```
// Load resource and replace source `listing` with target `listing`.
$('#listing').load('/myuri.php #listing');
// Load resource and replace source `contextActions` with target `contextActions`.
$('#contextActions').load('/myuri.php #contextActions');
```

Surely there must be a better way of doing this? I don't like the idea of having two load requests on the very same resource!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way of doing that.

Have `/myuri.php` return a **[JSON](http://www.json.org/)** object that contains the necessary data both for `#listing` and `#contextActions` and use a callback to assign it.

```
$.load('/myuri.php', {}, function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
   var data = $.parseJSON(responseText);
   $('#listing').html(data.listing);
   $('#contextActions').html(data.contextActions);
});
```