# jQuery load 2 divs from a page into 1 div

Tags: jquery

Okay, new to jQuery so hopefully this is an easy question and I am just missing something.
I want to load 2 divs from a page on my site to a div on another page when a link is clicked
something along the lines of:

```
$('#result').load('test.html #div1 #div2');
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
<a onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick='$("#col2").load("oldPage.htm #div1");'>Display content</a>
```

This works, but it only loads 1 Div, if I try to add another from the "oldPage" it doesn't work. Ideas? again keep in mind I am new to this.

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend you to not use `onclick='...'` anymore... We are in 2013!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load multiple fragments with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065299/load-multiple-fragments-with-jquery)

Comment: @Johnツ That would be fine, but what should I use?

Comment: @brian Use `$("a").on("click", function () { ... })` instead, from js side. You can pass any jQuery selector in `$(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a function to make this easier. I'll call it `load_divs`:

HTML:

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick='load_divs();return false;'>Display content</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function load_divs() {
    $("#col2").load("oldPage.htm #div1");
    $("#col2").append($("<div>").load("oldPage.htm #div2"));
}
```

An even better way to attach this event handler would be to give your `a` element an `id` and add the handler using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<a id="display_link" style="cursor: pointer;">Display content</a>
```

JS:

```
$("#display_link").click(function() {
    $("#col2").load("oldPage.htm #div1");
    $("#col2").append($("<div>").load("oldPage.htm #div2"));
});
```

Alternatively, if the divs you want to load are side-by-side in the DOM, you can wrap them in another div then load just that one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but it doesn't seem to be working for me it is still only pulling in the first div.

Comment: @brian are you sure the second div actually exists? did you check the error log? might want to post your current code too.

Comment: I will post my code soon I have to take out a lot, it is an internal site for work. I know the second div exists, I created it. Which error log, in the browser or firebug? Thanks again.

Comment: @brian the javascript error log. it's bound to tell you what's going on.

Comment: ah, gotcha, it says:                                          "Timestamp: 8/5/2013 2:34:41 PM
Warning: Error in parsing value for 'perspective-origin'.  Declaration dropped.
Source File: http://site/page.html#
Line: 0
Source Code:
NaNpx"

Comment: I never did get this to work but I think it had to do with some other stuff on my page conflicting with it, I am marking it answered as I think it will work when I can track some other things down. Thanks for your help.

Comment: yes, sorry, that error message does seem to indicate that the problem is elsewhere in your script.